# Can't answers be funny?

Tags: discussion

I noticed a [funny answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/46575/can-you-identify-how-software-is-used-within-a-domain) was removed, although I think it was spot on. And it made me laugh. I would like more answers like that :)

Funny answers arent allowed?

Answer (score 6):

No. I hate fun. Ask my kids.

Honestly, funny answers are allowed, as long as they are actually answers. That answer was not an earnest attempt to truly answer the question. It was flagged, and how can I honestly respond to someone flagging it that "yes, it violates the rules but I am going to leave it here because it made me breathe slightly stronger through my nose when I read it"? I can't. So I removed it.

Comment: This made me laugh too ;-) love you!

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same thing. I *almost* felt bad for getting 22 upvotes for [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/45573/how-many-test-steps-are-allowed-in-a-single-manual-test-case/45575#45575). But I figured it did answer the question, the funny part was just a bonus.

Comment: That would be my nominee for  SQA's Best Answer of 2020.